# Is L^p norm-closed in the bounded continuous functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

I wonder wether for a locally compact (for my purposes we'd also have unimodularity) group $G$ the L^p space $L^p(G)$ is a norm-closed subset of $C_b(G)$. The former space is of course meant to denote only those functions who are **also** bounded and continuous. In other words, the question is whether $L^p(G)\cap C_b(G)$ is norm closed in $C_b(G)$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the measure you put on $G$. If the measure is finite, then the answer is affirmative, because if $f_n\in L^p(G)$ is a sequence converging in $C_b(G)$ then it converges uniformly and when the measure is finite this implies that the limit function is also in $L^p(G)$. However, if the measure is infinite (for example, the real line being your locally compact group with the Lebesgue measure) then there are examples of uniformly convergent sequences of integrable, continuous functions whose limit is not integrable.

Comment: Hmmm I see. Just one slight variation:
Do you think the answer changes when one considers $L^{p+}$ instead of $L^p$?The former denoting all functions who are $L^q$ integrable for all $q>p$.